# How do I print the count result and table together in mysql?

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

How do I print the count result and table together in mysql?

```
SELECT friendName from Friend where userId = 'kdw8055' and type = 'F' and status = 'Y';

SELECT COUNT(*) from Friend where userId = 'kdw8055' and type = 'F' and status = 'Y';
```

I would like to print the above result at once. What should I do?

Comment: `select friendname, count(*) from friend where userId = 'kdw8055' and type = 'F' and status = 'Y' group by friendname;` might do it

Comment: just adhere those queries with `UNION ALL` such as `SELECT 'friendname' AS title, friendname ..... UNION ALL SELECT 'Count' ,COUNT(*)....`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: There's absolutely no need for two queries and a UNION here.

Comment: depends on how you want to look (row-wise or column-wise) @KenWhite

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: The poster didn't ask about multiple rows. They said *print the above result at once*, which would seem to indicate a single row produced by a single query.

Comment: *once* does not strictly mean *one row* @KenWhite

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in a single row, you can do it with a simple `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT friendName, count(*) from Friend 
where userId = 'kdw8055' and type = 'F' and status = 'Y'
GROUP BY friendname;
```